# How to create a custom function which i can turn it off on a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a bit of code once the page load so in the footer i have got:

```
$(function(){
  //code to run on page load
});
```

But then i need to stop that code to run on a

```
.click()
```

I was thinking of having a custom function which runs on page load and then be able to disabale that function on a click.

How to create a custom function which i can turn it off on a click?

Comment: What are you running in this function, is there a loop involved ?

Comment: i've updated my question maybe clearer

Comment: by "stop that code to run {on} a `.click`", do you mean you want to fire a click event, possibly on another element, after the code has finished running?

Comment: yes on a .click() i will run another code and stop what has run before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to add a flag/preference variable to your page, which dictates which logic can be executed and when.

Whenever code is then executed, just check the preference, i.e.

```
function myfunction () {
    ....
    if (code_may_run) {
        ....
        code_may_run = false;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: I updated the example a little bit to explain what I meant... but there may be a better Javascript way of doing things.